# How to reset a form after throwing a redirect in a form action

Tags: sveltekit

My server-side form action results in a `throw redirect(303, location)`. I can't figure out the right way to progressively enhance it.

```js
<form
    method="POST"
    use:enhance={({ form }) => {

        // Correctly resets the form.
        form.reset()
    
        return async ({ form, update, result}) => {
          // But resetting/invalidating here has no effect
          // form.reset()
          // await invalidateAll()
          // 
          // This works,
          // await goto(nextHref, {invalidateAll: true})

          update()
        };
      }}
>
```

Resetting the form from within the SubmitFunction does clear the contents. But then the user sees a blank form for some time.

I want to do this in the callback. But can't figure out the right way to do it.

- `form.reset()` and/or `invalidateAll()` followed by `update()` has no effect.
- Putting in a `goto(location, {invalidateAll: true})` does seem to work. But I don't understand why this does and the above doesn't.
- I could also put in some reactive logic to clear the specific input fields. But this seems messy.
- I've done it by using `afterNavigate`. But it would be good to know the right solution.

The issues seems to be related to https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5007

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Why do you need to reset when a redirect happens anyway?

Comment: I'm redirecting to another instance of the same form. For example to add multiple students to a class or multiple flashcards to a deck.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, using `formElement.reset(); update();` works just fine for me in the result handler. (`form` is deprecated since [v1.17.0](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/releases/tag/%40sveltejs%2Fkit%401.17.0), by the way.)